# traversing this with jquery gives me undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

When I click `.getdata`, I want to go from `.getdata` to `name=top` and read the value of whichever option is selected (in this case it's 0), but I'm having a hard time getting to it. I keep getting undefined.

This is my html. The `div class="main"` repeats so I can't simply select `input[name=top]`. It would have to be through traversing the tree to the closest  `input[name=top]`. Can someone get this right? I'm starting to think it's a browser error because I tried different options and all give me undefined.

```
<div class="main">
   <div class="branch">
       <div class="element">
          <label>top color:</label>
          <input type="radio" value="1" name="top">black
          <input type="radio" value="0" name="top" checked="checked">white
          <input type="radio" value="null" name="top">transparent
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="controls">
      <a class="getdata">get data</a>
   </div>           
</div>

<div class="main">
....    
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('a.getdata').click(function() {
    var val = $(this).closest('.main').find('input[name="top"]:checked').val();
});
```

- Place a [`click()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event on the `<a>` element
- On a click, use the [`closest()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method to traverse up to the `.main` element
- Then use the [`find()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method along with the  the [`attribute-equals-selector`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)  and the [`checked-selector`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) to get the checked `name="top"` radio.
- Finally use the [`val()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method to get its value.

Comment: Thank you. I think my mistake was that I was using closest() to find downstream and it wasn't working.

Comment: Citation needed! :) +1 for thoroughness.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".getdata").click(function(){
        selectedValue=$(this).parent().prev().children().children("input[name=top]:checked").val();
        console.log(selectedValue);
});
```